# How to center block of inline-blocks?

Tags: css

How do I make the green box (`.b`) tight around its contents so that I can horizontally center it?

```css
.c {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.a {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.b {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To clarify:

[image]

Comment: The issue is because of the nature of inline blocks. Since all of your .c elements are inline-blocks that, when all on a single line, would extend beyond the width of the container, they wrap to the next line (which is obviously the intention). Despite visually appearing to be less than full-width, it is because they are forced to wrap is why the container is pushed to it's limits. So either the contents or the container has to have a defined width.

I'm not sure if what you're trying to accomplish can be done with CSS alone. Would you be interested in a JS solution?

Comment: as i comment to the answer of @Tessa ... are all the `.c` supposed to be equal size ? as i thnk they can be dynamic size.

Comment: @TemaniAfif The `.c` elements can be a fixed size (width and height). The content doesn't vary much so I can set it explicitly if needed.

Comment: @Tessa I've tried with `float: left` instead of `display: inline-block` and couldn't get anywhere with that either. I'd prefer not to use a JS solution -- the page is supposed to be responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that will not make the .b to be smaller in order to fit all the .c but it will make the .c to be stretched a litte in order to avoid having the white spaces.

**UPDATE**

I added some media queries to make sure all the elements always stay the same width. Of course this is based on exact values, so for a generic solution we may need to include `calc` or some variable.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.c {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 80px;
  flex: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.b {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.b:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
}

@media all and (max-width:1110px) {
  .b:after {
    margin: 5px;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:1020px) and (max-width:1110px) {
  .b:after {
    flex: 10;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:930px) and (max-width:1020px) {
  .b:after {
    flex: 7.75;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:840px) and (max-width:930px) {
  .b:after {
    flex: 5.5;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:750px) and (max-width:840px) {
  .b:after {
    flex: 3.25;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:570px) and (max-width:660px) {
  .b:after {
    flex: 4.33;
  }
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to have done anything at all: https://i.imgur.com/L0Yk3YS.png

Comment: @mpen go full width .. you wanted b to be tight to it's content, right ? but the content is big so for small screen there is no effect. Or i missed something ?

Comment: Thanks. I've tried a whole bunch of stuff but none of it seems to work.

Comment: @mpen yes it's clear .. to be honest me too, am not able to find it :s. First time i face this ... if i don't find an answer in the next 10 min i will delete it then

Comment: @mpen check again my solution. I tried something to get rid of the white spaces by streching the .c in a certain way. Not sure if this is what you look for

Comment: That would work well enough for my needs *if only* the last element was the same width as the others. https://i.imgur.com/lhq1RF7.png

Comment: @mpen yes, try to reduce more the size and you will see ... the idea is that i added a hidden element (using :after) to avoid that last element to take all the width, so the hidden ellement will take the big part and this one will remaing 80px ... and you can see that when you will have two rows, all the element will have same width and only first row will stretch

Comment: @mpen by the way am gonna think about a solution, it's a bit challenging but i like such challenges :)

Comment: I don't know why they couldn't have just put an option in the flexbox spec to control the alignment of the last line. That's screwed me so many times now :'(

Comment: @mpen ok check again, i found a Crazy solution by using media query to change the flex of the hidden element to make the other stay same width .. but this will involve some calculation if you need to change the width of your element, but it can be a good start .. We can make it more complicated by using `calc` in order to make it more generic

Comment: That's kind of a pain, especially with my layout where my sidebar collapses at a certain breakpoint, which gives *more* room for my content. Nevertheless, this is basically what I ended up doing. Just a crapton of breakpoints. Thanks for your help, I think this is about as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment that I wasn't sure if it could be done with CSS alone, I created a quick JS/jQuery solution to calculate the width based on the first row of contents.

```js
function resizeGrid() {
  var rowPos = 0;
  var col = 0;
  $('.b').removeAttr('style');
  $('.c').each(function() {
    var thisRowPos = $(this).offset().top;
    if (thisRowPos != rowPos) {
      if (rowPos != 0) {
        /* Break out of the $.each() loop */
        return false;
      } else {
        col++;
      }
      rowPos = thisRowPos;
    } else {
      col++;
    }
  });
  $('.b').css('width', $('.c').outerWidth(true) * col + 'px');
  console.log('Number of columns: ' + col);
}

$(window).on('resize', resizeGrid);
resizeGrid();
```

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.a {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.b {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.b:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.c {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.c table {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.c table td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>x x x x x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but you are supposing that all the .c are equal. Am not sure it's the case, because if they were equal we can easily then use media query. Try put random content on .c

Comment: @TemaniAfif The `.c` have fixed width/height, but the container does not. I want it to stretch as you resize the window which will cause the `.c`s to reflow.

Comment: I see where you're going with the solution @Tessa. It's not ideal, but it's the only solution I've seen so far. Your implementation seems a little off though: https://i.imgur.com/gbZdZ06.png It's miscalculating the number of cols. The scrollbar might nudging it? Either way, it's too brittle.

Comment: Glad you found a solution @mpen ! I had whipped this up waiting for a plane at the airport, so not too much time was spent on it.