# How to change div sizes, so it would fill 100% of the containers space?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a lot of divs, as you can see in the picture. It all looks fine, but once I resize the window of the browser. It doesn't fill the entire space.  [image]

Heres how it looks on a little smaller window:

[image]

How do I make it to always fill that empty space on any window heights, including mobiles.

Update:

https://jsfiddle.net/2rswx78a/

```
.item {
    width:100.9px;height:100.9px;border-radius:6px;background-color:#C6C6C6;display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: 1. Can you please share a code snippet? 2. Just from how it looks, I would say that In the smaller screen the space on the right isn't big enough for another box to fit in. That's including the margins on both sizes.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Comment: Yes, but how do I make it so it would fill the entire space and change the images width and height accordingly?

Comment: Can you produce your error in a jsfiddle

Comment: I just added a jsfiddle, please take a look

Comment: you cannot fill this spaces, here is a similar question where we faced the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479571/how-to-center-block-of-inline-blocks

Answer (score 0):

dont give your items a fixed width, ofcourse this can´t work responsive.

I suggest using bootstrap columns to make this work.

Or writing your own class.
E.g.

```
.item{
width: calc(100% / 7);
}
@media(max-width: 1200px){
.item{
width: 20%;
   }
}
```

And ofc more media queries for the smaller devices.You then need a larger picture and should make it width: 100%, height: auto to make it fill the width of the columns. Ofc all pictures need to have the same width/height ratio

Here´s the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2rswx78a/5/

Comment: why downvote it? That´s exactly how it works. making your img width fixed CANT! work responsive. you need to work with percentages which you create yourself or with bootstrap columns.